# Orika no mapping of null elements in list

Tags: java, null, mapper, orika

I have the following class:

```
public class A{
    List<AA> aaList;

    public A(List<AA> aaList){
        this.aaList = aaList;
    }

    //getters and setters + default constructor

    public class AA {
        String aaString;
        public AA(String aaString){
            this.aaString = aaString;
        }

        //getters and setters + default constructor
    }
}
```

And I want to have two objects of the same class, let's say:

```
A a = new A(Arrays.asList(new A.AA(null)));
A a2 = new A(Arrays.asList(new A.AA("test")));
```

and when I map `a` to `a2`, `a2` should remain `test` because `a` has a `null`.

How can I configure this with `Orika`?

I tried something like:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(A.AA.class, A.AA.class)
            .mapNulls(false)
            .byDefault()
            .register();

    mapperFactory.classMap(A.class, A.class)
            .mapNulls(false)
            .customize(new CustomMapper<A, A>() {
                @Override public void mapAtoB(A a, A a2,
                        MappingContext context) {
                    map(a.getAAList(), a2.getAAList());
                }
            })
            .byDefault()
            .register();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you map `a` to `a2`? I mean did you try? I am confused about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified code snippet that worked for me:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(A.class, A.class)
    .mapNulls(false)
    .customize(new CustomMapper<A, A>() {
        @Override
        public void mapAtoB(A a, A a2, MappingContext context) {
            // 1. Returns new list with not null
            List<A.AA> a1List = a.getAaList().stream()
                    .filter(a1 -> a1.getAaString() != null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            // 2. Merges all the elements from 'a2' list into 'a' list
            a1List.addAll(a2.getAaList());

            // 3. Sets the list with merged elements into the 'a2'
            a2.setAaList(a1List);
        }
    })
    .register();
```

Note, that the `.byDefault()` should be removed in order for the custom mapper to work properly.